# (SQL) SELECT the average value with interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

Sample data:

[image]

I want to select the average value every 5 minutes, for example.

The result should be a list like this:

```
3
8
```

The functions for this should be: `AVG(VALUE), DATEDIFF(datepart, startdate, enddate) with datepart=minute and/or DATEADD (datepart, number, date)`

I didn't find an interval function (Transact-SQL)

**Update**

Example of what I really want to do here:

[image: sample]

I want the average values between points to plot a trendline I have to change the "cluster" means the resolution to calculate it. In this example my cluster is 1. 2 would mean, that I'll get the average from the first 3 value points. I hope i did explained it well!

Comment: Are you always wanting the intervals to start on the hour (08:00, 08:05, 08:10)?

Comment: Not only hour; starting on days it interesting for me, too!

Comment: Sure, days is a separate thing (and easy). It's a simple solution if you want it to start on the hour. The only issue is that your result wouldn't be 3, 8. it would be 2, 7, 10 because line 10 on your data would be the start of a new 5 minute period. I'll provide an answer below to show you what i mean

Comment: You are 100% right :-)

Comment: Excellent, glad to help. Feel free to upvote any answers that have been useful to you. If one has fixed your issue then you can also mark that as the accepted answer.

Comment: Rich, when the time isn't starting on 08:00, but with 08:01 the AvgResult should be 3 and 7

Comment: ok, then go and work it out. I can't guess what you mean when you're not being very clear. Notice my first comment on your original question asking if the intervals should start on the hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your intervals to start on the hour then this is a pretty simple solution.

Sample Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SampleData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SampleData
CREATE TABLE #SampleData (ID int identity(1,1), Date datetime, Value int)
INSERT INTO #SampleData (Date, Value)
VALUES
 ('2016-01-01 08:31:00.000',1.00000)
,('2016-01-01 08:32:00.000',2.00000)
,('2016-01-01 08:33:00.000',3.00000)
,('2016-01-01 08:34:00.000',4.00000)
,('2016-01-01 08:35:00.000',5.00000)
,('2016-01-01 08:36:00.000',6.00000)
,('2016-01-01 08:37:00.000',7.00000)
,('2016-01-01 08:38:00.000',8.00000)
,('2016-01-01 08:39:00.000',9.00000)
,('2016-01-01 08:40:00.000',10.00000)
```

Query

```
SELECT
dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,sd.Date) / 5 * 5, 0) Interval
,AVG(sd.Value) AvgResult
FROM #SampleData sd
GROUP BY dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,sd.Date) / 5 * 5, 0)
```

Result

```
Interval                    AvgResult
2016-01-01 08:30:00.000     2
2016-01-01 08:35:00.000     7
2016-01-01 08:40:00.000     10
```

If you want the periods to show differently then you could do this;

```
SELECT
dateadd(minute, (datediff(minute,0,sd.Date) / 5 * 5) + 3, 0) Interval
,AVG(sd.Value) AvgResult
FROM #SampleData sd
GROUP BY dateadd(minute, (datediff(minute,0,sd.Date) / 5 * 5) + 3, 0)
```

to give this result;

```
Interval                    AvgResult
2016-01-01 08:33:00.000     2
2016-01-01 08:38:00.000     7
2016-01-01 08:43:00.000     10
```

As per your comments, you could use this query to round your actual average of the instances in the interval to the nearest minute;

```
SELECT
a.AVGDate
,AVG(sd.Value) AvgResult
FROM #SampleData sd
JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,DATEADD(s,30,CAST(AVG(CAST(sd.Date AS Float)) AS Datetime))),0) AVGDate
        ,dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,sd.Date) / 5 * 5, 0) Interval
    FROM #SampleData sd
    GROUP BY dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,sd.Date) / 5 * 5, 0) 
) a
ON dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,sd.Date) / 5 * 5, 0) = a.Interval
GROUP BY a.AVGDate
```

Result;

```
AVGDate                     AvgResult
2016-01-01 08:33:00.000     2
2016-01-01 08:37:00.000     7
2016-01-01 08:40:00.000     10
```

Comment: Rich, actually that's it! But no the first time should be 2016-01-01 08:33:00.000, because that is the middle (of date) of the first 5 dataset.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, take a look and see if it's what you're after.

Comment: Nearly right. The second period is 08:37:00 not 08:37:00, beause it's from ID5 to ID9. That the last difficult :)

Comment: @Killcycle It would be better if you would give all of the information up front. Also, a sense of curiosity and taking the challenge yourself once people have given you most of the answer will help in this career line. I've updated my answer with a subquery to work out the actual average of the datetime fields in the interval as requested.

Comment: I've guilty conscience about this...for tooking the challange to you. There is only one last issue: The first AvgResult should be 3, not 2. What's the problem with avg()?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference in minutes from time 0 and divide by five for aggregation:

```
select min(date), avg(value)
from t
group by (datediff(minute, 0, date) - 1) / 5; -- SQL Server does integer division
```

Comment: Thats what i get. That's wrong, you see?
1 2016-01-01 08:31:00.000 2.500000
2 2016-01-01 08:35:00.000 7.500000
3 2016-01-01 08:40:00.000 10.000000
P.S.: How to nextline here in this answer post, for formatting my data? :)

Comment: just subtract 1 from the result of datediff function and it will work as expected. ie: group by (datediff(minute, 0, d)-1) / 5