# Get average of rows group by value intervals

Tags: sql, average

I have a table as follows:

```
ID | Value
 1     5  
 1    1000
 1    1500
 2    1000
 2    1800
 3    40
 3    1000
 3    1200
 3    2000
 3    2500
```

I want to obtain the average of each ID groupped by a given range `r` of value. For instance, if in this case `r=1000`, The expected result would be:

```
ID | Value
 1     5  
 1    1250
 2    1400
 3    40
 3    1100
 3    2250
```

I have seen that this can be done with time intervals as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095957/sql-select-the-average-value-with-interval). My question is, how can I perform this type of group by operation for integer/float types?

Comment: You might try: `SELECT id, AVG(value) FROM thetable GROUP BY id, value/1000` – at least postgres accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way:

```
SELECT id, avg(value) as AvgValue
FROM (SELECT id, value, ROUND(value/1000, 0) AS range FROM yourtable) t
GROUP BY id, range
```